# BBDB (version 3) search at point or for selected text

Tags: bbdb

I'd like to start a BBDB search directly with the word at the current cursor `point` or with the current selection.  Is there already a short-cut or at least a function for these functionalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this functionality is already implemented.

AFAICS the functionality is provided e.g. by

```
(defun bbdb-word-at-point ()
  "Ask bbdb about word at point."
  (interactive)
  (bbdb (thing-at-point 'word t)))
```